# Can't import files defined as aliases in tsconfig.json under paths

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, nestjs

I am trying to share enums and dtos between my backend and frontend (NestJS at the back, React at the front. Both use typescript).

To do so, I tried to add my "shared" files to the client's `tsconfig.json` > `compilerOptions` > `paths` like so:

```json
    "paths": {
      "@project/shared/*": [
        "../server/src/common/*"
      ]
    }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. When I run the react client, it throws "webpack Module not found."

This is my file structure:
[image]
`App.tsx` consumes the `TestEnum` from the server's common directory.

Comment: Please share your file structure.

Comment: @lukasl-dev edited the question to include the file structure as an image

Comment: I think you could make a package that holds the shared enums then import that package to both projects.

Comment: @ColinHale Yeah, but I want to avoid this approach. Every source I found on the web tells you to add it as a path for typescript, and in fact, it works in another project of mine, but not on new react apps (even if I copy the node_modules directory to make sure versions are the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to share what I had to do in my projects and file structure to share models, types, enums, entities, etc., between the server (NestJS) and the client (React).

First of all, I started setting up npm workspaces to achieve a monorepo, as @sungryeol described in his detailed [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72959990/8031115) (thanks for it).

Unfortunately, it was only half of the way to making it work. So here is a solution I came up with (remarks are welcome) in addition to workspaces:

##### Client (react)

`create react app` is designed to compile code only from the `src` directory. Because I am using typescript in my shared code, I need to compile it to make it work. To make CRA compile my shared code, I used [`react-app-rewired`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-app-rewired) to modify the webpack config with the following `config-overrides.js` file:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
    const babelLoaderModule = require.resolve('babel-loader');
    const rule = config.module.rules[1].oneOf.find(rule => rule.loader === babelLoaderModule);
    rule.include = [
        rule.include,
        path.resolve(__dirname, '../shared')
    ];
    return config;
}
```

React finally started accepting my shared code without any issues.

##### Server (NestJS)

Since NestJS uses `tsc` as the compiler, I had to specify the directory of the shared code in the server's `tsconfig.json` as a path.

```json
    "paths": {
      "@managed-businesses/shared/*": [
        "../shared/*"
      ]
    }
```

This made my shared code compile when I started the nest app, but it couldn't find the entry point, as it compiled the code in the following structure

```
dist
├── server
│   ├── src
│       ├── main.d.ts
│       └── main.js
├── shared
│   ├── dtos
│   └── enums
└── tsconfig.build.tsBuildInfo
```

while Nest lookup for the `src/main.js` file to be at the root of the `dist` directory.
To fix that, I had to tweak the `nest-cli.json` file to lookup the file in the `dist/server/src` directory. Here is my new config for nest-cli.

```json
{
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "server/src"
}
```

After all, the server finally works with the shared code, and I don't need to duplicate it between the projects. I am probably missing something or did something incorrectly, and I'll be happy to know if there is a better way, but at the bottom line, it works.

Comment: as far as it works, it's actually a brilliant idea. you saved your time and effort. consider my suggestion as an alternative. here's an improvement idea for your work though:

- use `@craco/craco` + `react-app-alias` instead of exposing the internal by react-app-rewired. it even supports extreme settings, such as using different transpiler+bundler(esbuild, swc...). exposing cra internal should be avoided if one can. it'll bring unwanted side effects later.

- `tsc` can also access project root via typescript `references` option. please refer to official document.

Comment: @sungryeol thank you, I'll definitely look into it and try to avoid manipulating cra internals.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to achieve is essentially a **monorepo**. **The best way to solve the dependency issue is of monorepo is to refer each package as a separate package**; it's clear in the comment that you do not want to do so but it's de facto standard already.

It's because importing what's outside the workspace(where the `package.json` lies) is **really really bad idea**. I've tried this but not recommend it; the package managers, bundlers and IDEs(let's say "the tools") will work strangely due to conflict issues:

1. the file's root has it's own config such as `tsconfig.json, package.json` which can conflict with project's setting. it is not clear which one they should follow.
2. the tools usually have their boundary due to security issues; if the tool can leave the project root, it can do something sneaky, such as compromising internal system files.
3. when deploying the apps in the clouds, they(client/server) have to stick together all the time. it becomes devOps issue.

## Solution

the best way to deal with this, is to use workspace feature of package managers. here the term **workspace** means separate packages inside monorepo. npm's explanation of workspace clearly fits to your settings.

> Workspaces is a generic term that refers to the set of features in the npm cli that provides support to managing multiple packages from your local file system from within a singular top-level, root package.

npm and yarn both support workspace features.

- [npm workspace](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/workspaces)
- [yarn workspace](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/workspaces/)

from now on, the project structure should be perceived as this.

```
project root --> place workspace setting here
|-package root(client) --> workspace
|-package root(server) -> workspace too
```

most workspace features support 'hoist' feature. without publishing the actual packages, your packages in different folders can be imported and referred as if they are published, via softlink(symlink, something like shortcut in windows). it's same as typescript config's path alias but it actually creates a real file so that the tool won't have any side effects.

to do so,  setup workspace config at your project root so that the tool can perceive this packages as workspaces.

```bash
# create shared package directory first
$(projectRoot) mkdir shared
```

```js
// projectRoot/package.json
{
  "name": "project",
  "workspaces": [
    "client",
    "server",
    "shared"
  ]
}

// projectRoot/client/package.json
{
  "name": "@project/client",
  "private": true, // set this to private so that this won't get published by mistake
  "packages": {
     // your default packages 
     "@project/shared": "1.0.0" // <-- version has to match
  }
  // ...
}

// projectRoot/server/package.json
{
  "name": "@project/server",
  "private": true
  // ...
}

// projectRoot/shared/package.json
{
  "name": "@project/shared",
  "private": false, // make it public so that you can publish it later
  "version": "1.0.0"
  // ...
}
```

```bash
# remove all `node_modules` folder.

$(projectRoot) rm -rf client/node_modules
$(projectRoot) rm -rf server/node_modules

# reinstall node_modules so that the projects can be symlinked as packages.
$(projectRoot) npm i
```

then it'll work as workspace from now on and the packages will be linked. it's that simple!

## Caveat

- as you can see, cleaning up and bootstrapping the package is bit of a work. that's where monorepo tool(i.g. [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna)) comes handy; try expand your monorepo knowledge from here.
- if it's deployed to AWS, it'll probably work. however, it's best to publish the `@project/shared` package to npm in the end. many cloud instances don't support symlinks(vercel, netlify...) still, symlink is useful in local/dev environment.

## Edit

here's working demo:https://github.com/rabelais88/monorepo-workspace-npm

check readme before proceed. after typing `npm install`, symlinked hollow modules are seen. as far as they are there, scripts will run fine

[image]

edit 2: after setting up the workspace, some dependencies or all the dependencies will be placed at project root instead of each workspace. it is intentional by design, to avoid having duplicated packages in each workspace. this might surprise some but actually very useful in maintaining bigger systems.

Comment: I tried to set up a workspace with npm, but I can't run `npm install` from the client directory, as it says `@project/shared` is not found. Also, I don't know if this is the intended behavior (from what I saw on npm docs, it doesn't), but when I run `npm install` from the root of the workspace, it installs all dependencies from all workspaces and stores them in the `node_modules` root directory.

Comment: @r0den It is intended behavior. as I said in the answer, files in node_modules will be copied to workspaces' subdirectory as symlink(as a hollow refers to original - to save spaces for duplicated packages in workspaces). since the dependencies are installed, I think it is worked properly. not recognizing `@project/shared` is another problem. I'll provide working demo for this.

Comment: Actually, the installed dependencies aren't copied as symlinks; instead, they were installed from the npm registry (at least vscode doesn't show the symlink icon for them).

Comment: @r0den I've added a working demo. hope you like it. ☺️

Comment: Thank you, in your example, the symlinks work fine. But, here is what happens in my project when I try to set up a workspace. All dependencies are being installed in `<root>/node_modules` https://imgur.com/a/XayCxnC

Comment: @r0den that's also intended behavior. all module files are located in project root so that the tool can detect dependency and manage them easily. by avoiding having real file at the each workspaces, it can also save storage spaces & install time too. that's what makes the monorepo remarkably useful in bigger projects.

Comment: what about typescript? Will I need to compile them manually each time I change them?

Comment: @r0den you don't have to. just refer to the package's typescript source instead of compiled one. because the files are symlink, it is accessible just like plain files in node_modules folder.
`import yourFunction from '@projectRoot/shared/src/yourFunction.ts`
it must feel very confusing, because monorepo is eye-widening concept. I also learned this by many trials and errors. 

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me with typescript. https://i.imgur.com/Rs1Wwwz.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246397/discussion-between-r0den-and-sungryeol).